# force directed graph - how to sum the connections between nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to find a way to sum the connections (volume) between nodes. I have an array:

```
var links = 
[
{"source":"a0","target":"a0","s_portfolio":"a","t_portfolio":"a","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP","File_Desc":"","DataName":""},
{"source":"a1","target":"a2","s_portfolio":"a","t_portfolio":"c","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP","File_Desc":"Date","DataName":"Dates.01012016"},
{"source":"a1","target":"a2","s_portfolio":"a","t_portfolio":"c","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP","File_Desc":"Address","DataName":"Address.01012016"},
{"source":"a1","target":"a0","s_portfolio":"b","t_portfolio":"a","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP","File_Desc":"Customer Name","DataName":"Customer Name.01012016"},
{"source":"a2","target":"a3","s_portfolio":"c","t_portfolio":"d","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"DB","File_Desc":"Books","DataName":"Books.01012016"},
{"source":"a4","target":"a3","s_portfolio":"e","t_portfolio":"d","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"DB","File_Desc":"Magazines","DataName":"Magazines.01012016"},
{"source":"a4","target":"a3","s_portfolio":"e","t_portfolio":"d","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"DB","File_Desc":"Employees","DataName":"Employees.01012016"},
{"source":"a4","target":"a3","s_portfolio":"e","t_portfolio":"d","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"DB","File_Desc":"Zip","DataName":"Zip.01012016"},
{"source":"a3","target":"a4","s_portfolio":"d","t_portfolio":"e","SOURCE_TYPE":"DB","DES_TYPE":"APP","File_Desc":"PQT","DataName":"PQT.01012016"},
{"source":"a1","target":"a2","s_portfolio":"a","t_portfolio":"c","SOURCE_TYPE":"APP","DES_TYPE":"APP","File_Desc":"YTD","DataName":"YTD.01012016"}
];
```

1. s_portfolio and t_portfolio are the groups to which nodes belong.
2. SOURCE_TYPE and DES_TYPE are the kinds of nodes - database or application
3. File_Desc is a type of file being sent
4. DataName is the name of the file

Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/Alexey_D3/xhx3L8jn/11/

Comment: Are you looking for front end design suggestions or do you have a specific problem?

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado - I hope it makes more sence.

Comment: @ Four_lo - My goal is to make link width dynamically changed based on the number of connections between the 2 nodes. Ex: 1 connection -1 px, 2 connections - 2 px, etc... I was helped to do so, but on a smaller array having source and target only. Now, when added other columns, it does not work.

Comment: @echonax - correct.

Comment: I think it does work but your scale is too small. The width of the connections between the five nodes are contingent on a value you are assigning where you define "link".  Where you assign a number either, 1, 2.5 or 5. I do no believe you are getting any that fall into the 5 threshold but they are determining width. You may need to increase your scale of measurement to show the differences. LMK how that works

Comment: @Four_lo - I think what you see is opacity. The initial opacity is 0.6 and when one link overlays another one it looks brighter, but not thicker.

Comment: I tested this change it became larger. If you can revert your fiddle back to the one that I tested on before I can save the changes and forward you a link

Comment: @echonax - I like what you suggested, but not sure how I can use it.

Comment: In other words I do not have any problems with columns: source, target, s_portfolio, t_portfolio, SOURCE_TYPE, DES_TYPE. I cannot pass File_Desc and DataName properly, so later I could create a function where on link click I would be able to see all the files being transferred between the 2 nodes.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Alexey_D3/xhx3L8jn/12/